# Which type of data was pass to my intent android

Tags: android, android-intent

My MainActivity class contains an EditText, a button who allow the user to choose a picture and another button (send) who create a second intent.

The user can edit the EditText or/and pick a picture. My purpose here, is to know (and display it in the second intent), by using , which kind of data was send to the second intent.

I'm aware that I have to use this in the AndroidManifest.xml

```
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND"/>
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
<data android:mimeType="image/*"/>
<data android:mimeType="text/plain"/>
</intent-filter>
```

And then this

```
// Get the intent that started this activity
Intent intent = getIntent();
Uri data = intent.getData();

// Figure out what to do based on the intent type
if (intent.getType().equals("text/plain") && intent.getType().indexOf("image/") != -1) {
    // Display "Text edited and picture picked"
else if (intent.getType().indexOf("image/") != -1) {
    // Display "Picture picked"
} else if (intent.getType().equals("text/plain")) {
    // Display "Text edited"
} else //Display "Nothing"
```

But I don't really understand what connects all of this. How filters are used? And what did I have to write in my "Send" function?

Comment: You should know the type of data being sent, especially if you're the one sending it.  Rather than having a single intent action encapsulate multiple data types, why not just create actions for each type?  Then, in your AndroidManifest.xml, you can declare an intent-filter for each action you define.

Comment: Android Developer site has an in depth overview of Intents and Intent Filters: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html